# How can I ignore build directory in Subclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, build, subclipse

After build, I got tons of class files in build directory which is automatically generated. I don't want to commit them, so I tried to ignore them using `Team -> Add to svn:ignore`, but they are already grayed out.

[image]

I tried to remove the build directory with `Project -> Clean`, but interestingly Subclipse still has them when I tried to commit.

What went wrong? How can I ignore the build directory in Subclipse?

[image]

Comment: For some reason Tortoisesvn is the my favorite tool to add svn options.  It works like a charm.  I usually do it there, commit, then finally update my IDE copy.  For me, it is a pain in the neck to do it in the IDE svn plugin, sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to revert (team -> revert) beforehand to enable the (team -> add to svn) item. 
I'm not sure this is relevant to this change, but I had to execute `svn update` manually in order to remove some errors.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot ignore a file which is already in the svn repository. Delete that file from the repository and then try it again

Answer (score 1):

I think they already got added in the version control view and not committed yet. I hope you do n't see your files in your `subclipse` repository. If so, try performing a project-> team -> cleanup first.

If this doesn't work, please let me know, I will share you the steps to perform the clean-up manually.

Please note: By `clean`, I am not referring project clean but I am referring `repository cache cleanup` which is maintained in `.svn` folder of your project folders.