# Subclipse: How to add the default output folder to version control (*.class files)?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I am using eclipse 4.2 and Subclipse 1.8.20.

I am trying to add the contents of /WebContent/WEB-INF/classes to version control (this is also the default output folder of my project).

First let me state that this is possible with TortoiseSVN. I do understand why by default Subclipse ignores this directory, and I tried to change the Team settings, but I am not seeing a relevant entry for *.class files:

[image]

Is this at all possible with Subclipse?

More info:

- Old an unanswered similar question: http://subclipse.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1047&dsMessageId=473163
- Same topic but opposite question: [How can I ignore build directory in Subclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982579/how-can-i-ignore-build-directory-in-subclipse)

Answer (score 2):

It is a horribly bad idea to version your build directory.  Every time Eclipse does an auto-build it will cause all of the files to need to be committed again.

To answer your question, all Eclipse team providers automatically ignore any resource that is marked as "Derived" by Eclipse.  The Derived flag is set on files that are created by the Eclipse builders.  If you select one of these files that are ignored in Eclipse, right click and choose Properties.  Navigate to the Eclipse Resource page.  There will be a bunch of checkboxes.  You should see that one of these is labelled Derived and will likely be checked.

Do not try to change the checkbox value.  I am just pointing out where you can see and confirm this.

Comment: So, are you saying it is not possible? Or just that my idea is horrible? I do see the derived flag on the files inside the classes folder, but not on the 'classes' folder itself. I also just noticed that Subclipse actively unversions the contents of the 'classes' folder during a project clean rebuild (after I've added them with TortoiseSVN).

Comment: Both. Don't do it. It is not exactly fair to say Subclipse is going this.  When Eclipse builds something it deletes the files.  Because the files are versioned, Eclipse will fire the API to tell the team provider to delete them. Subversion is not a deployment tool.  Do not try to version your build artifacts.

Comment: Hm, I would have expected that derived resources would be ignored by team providers (neither added nor deleted). Anyway too bad I don't have a choice. The whole point of that "Ignored Resources" settings page seems to be to give the developer freedom of choice. But not in my case, I guess.

Comment: Ignored Resources, Derived Resources, svn:ignore all control the same thing, and that is which unversioned files should be ignored from Adding to version control.  Once the file is versioned, there are no settings to ignore changes to those files.